# Install app on jailed iPhone, which is not available on App Store

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, iphone

Is there a way to install an app, which is not available on the App Store, without doing a jailbreak?

Comment: Where *is* it available then? Do you mean you have the .ipa file? Is it signed for Enterprise distribution?

Comment: exactly, i downloaded an .ipa file from the web. no it's only for my personal use.

Comment: The app was once available in the App Store, but I couldn't find it anymore. Only place I found on was in the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the .ipa file is signed for Enterprise distribution or you have a provisioning profile for the app from the app's developer, you won't be able to install the app without jailbreaking.

Comment: I made it this far, that the app is in iTunes. After double-clicking the .ipa file iTunes opened and said "Your security preferences allow installation of only apps from the Mac App Store and identified developers." For this purpose I made an exception in system preferences->security & privacy->general->open anyway.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't go further than having it in iTunes

Answer (score 0):

If the app was available you can restore the .ipa file. The app will show in the list of apps in iTunes on your iOS device and you choose to install.

Note I have installed an app which is no longer in the App Store but which I had got from App Store some time before. I did this after I did a factory reset. I think these were the steps but this is from memory so the details might be wrong but you definitely can do it

Comment: I hadn't downloaded the app back then, when it was still available, thus it's not in my list of apps in iTunes. I wanted to downloaded and pay (5$) for it now, before I noticed it isn't online anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you will be able to install it is if the application you want is open source.

This is because Apple has released Xcode 7 that now allows you to install applications to your iOS device without needing a developers account. The only down side is you cannot install IPAs or .apps this way as far as I know. This will NOT allow you to install jailbreak tweaks however.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via Profiles, in setting if you install a new profile, you would be able to install apps that are not there in AppStore 
That's how a Semi Jailbreak works, it doesn't exploit the iOS version completely. It installs a profile with which it installs Jailbreaking Package.

To know about Semi Jailbreak visit, http://m.pangu8.com/83.html